# Python subprocess.call blocking

Tags: python

I am trying to run an external application in Python with subprocess.call. From what I've read it subprocess.call isn't supposed to block unless you call Popen.wait, but for me it is blocking until the external application exits. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in `subprocess` is actually pretty simple and readable. Just see the [3.3](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/subprocess.py) or [2.7](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/subprocess.py) version (as appropriate) and you can tell what it's doing.

For example, `call` looks like this:

```
def call(*popenargs, timeout=None, **kwargs):
    """Run command with arguments.  Wait for command to complete or
    timeout, then return the returncode attribute.

    The arguments are the same as for the Popen constructor.  Example:

    retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])
    """
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
        try:
            return p.wait(timeout=timeout)
        except:
            p.kill()
            p.wait()
            raise
```

You can do the same thing without calling `wait`. Create a `Popen`, don't call `wait` on it, and that's exactly what you want.

Answer (score 5):

You're reading the docs wrong.  According to them:

```
subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)
```

Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.

Comment: Oh, okay. How do I duplicate the functionality of, say, calling os.spawnl with the option P_NOWAIT?

Comment: @dpitch40 - http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-the-os-spawn-family.